# How do I thank editors?

Tags: discussion, edits

A few months ago I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49543182/open-a-qt-creator-buffer-in-emacs) which was in danger of being closed. A group of editors stepped in and cleaned up my question, leading to a good answer.

I believe adding a thanks comment to the original question is frowned on as off-topic. So how do I go about thanking these helpful individuals?

Comment: Learn from it and use the knowledge gained from said edits moving forward.

Comment: @KevinB, the next time I need to ask a question, I plan to review the edit history of the linked question, as a reminder. I still want to send a belated thanks to the folks involved.

Comment: Consider a bounty on one of their good posts.

Comment: @Hans [srsly](https://github.com/makulik/C-PlusPlus-Compact-for-Beginners/blob/master/C%2B%2BCompact-for-Beginners.png)?

Comment: To see if one skips traditional "why some @#$@#$@ edited my post" comment and rage revert is rewarding enough :)

Comment: It is nothing special. That is what we do here. Plenty of [ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11232/158100)  ...

Comment: Related: [Etiquette for thanking an editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11226/191655).

Comment: What @KevinB said. I've edited *many* questions, always hoping that someone will learn by example and write/edit better questions in the future. Do that and we all win.

Comment: If the editors in question have less than 2k they will get a score of +2 for any edit (making it a kind of reward)..

Comment: @DonWakefield Thank you for asking about thanking! :) See also a community wiki answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374934/578690). Using "dupe target" on SE to reach a wider audience.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you feel that it was a truly exceptional edit and you feel forever indebted then on your question which was edited you ***could*** choose to add one comment per editor you wish to thank:

> @rene Your edit was greatly appreciated and helped me to xyz after realizing abc!

and/or

> @JoshCaswell Your edit was greatly appreciated and helped me to xyz after realizing abc!

Even though their usernames won't autocomplete, they will be pinged per the details found at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/235923

I recommend letting the comments sit for a day to make sure they see it and then delete them.

In general, "thank you"s are noise so tread lightly.

At any rate, learning from the edits to make excellent questions in the future is the best way to positively impact the community.

If the day ever comes where edits are no longer needed because everyone asks good questions then I am sure mods and valuable users all around this site would simultaneously burst into tears of joy.

Comment: I wanted to add answer "do nothing" (because they don't expect thank when doing edit), but idea with deleted later ping comments is excellent.

Comment: I wouldn't be happy if everyone who get their post edited by me would ping me ....

Comment: @rene but, but, but, it's "welcoming" :'(

Comment: That day would never come.

Comment: @ManojKumar not with that attitude!

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Certainly not! :-)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus With saritical meaning? ... We all know that "be nice" and/or "welcoming" on this site doesn't mean "say 'thanks' in the comment".

Comment: @user202729 Plainly saying "thanks" is weak, basic, and noisy; expressing gratitude and internalization is a craft which I can respect. Please read the entire post to get an idea of the difference between "thanks" and gratitude.

Answer (score 45):

In general, you don't, at least not directly. In this specific case, at least one of them is likely to see this post and feel good. At least, I think they'll feel good about it.

Generally, the best way to thank an editor on Stack Overflow is to learn from their edits. See what they did to improve your post, and learn to do so yourself. Once you're good at doing so for yourself, pay it forward and help new users who need those edits as well.

In this way, you don't only thank the editor, you also do a little to make the site a better place and pay the site back. I'm glad editors were able to step in and save your post, and I hope you can do so for others in the future.

Answer (score 13):

> So how do I go about thanking these helpful individuals?

Things I could think of:

1. A timely self destructing comment pinging the editor
2. Improve your post by further editing, leave a contrib to the editor

If you're not comfortable with these, just leave everything as it is. It's fine such.

Comment: Possibly worth clarifying, while the usernames won't autocomplete, editors *can* be pinged, you just have to manually fill in their username. :)

Comment: They can _be pinged theoretically_ to be precise, yes :3 @Catija

Comment: How do I create "timely self destructing" comment? I can make *normal* rude comment, so it will be quickly "destructed" by moderator (not by me - yay!), but I have no clue, how to add "time" to it.

Comment: @Sinatr _'Timely self destructing'_ just needs some self discipline :3

Answer (score -20):

If you're really thankful, you could upvote some of their answers or questions provided they're reasonable (and you agree with them), or edit their questions so that they can get better answers, or answer questions they have.

Would be a more "materialistic" thank you.

Comment: No, please don't. I rather get my reputation because someone found my answer useful, not because they went over my profile  due to me spotting and fixing a typo somewhere (or any other substantial edit for that matter)

Comment: This advice runs counter to the guidance on what sorts of voting is and isn't acceptable. You should vote on content based on whether you think it's valuable or not - just like it's inappropriate to go find someone's other posts and downvote them because you have a grudge against the author, you also shouldn't be seeking out someone's posts and arbitrarily upvoting them to "thank" the author for an action unrelated to those posts.

Comment: Also, doing this will likely (depending on your definition of "some") just get your votes reversed anyway.

Comment: What's a "Spiritual" thank you? :-)